# SQL query min startdate max enddate across multiple rows

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

SQL Server 2008 R2

I have data like this:

```
+---------+--------+-------------+-------------+
| SchedId |  AdId  |  StartDate  |   EndDate   |
+---------+--------+-------------+-------------+
| 335779  | 179911 | 2017-01-04  | 2017-01-04  |
| 335780  | 179911 | 2017-01-05  | 2017-01-05  |
| ...     |        |             |             |
| 335802  | 179911 | 2017-01-31  | 2017-01-31  |
+---------+--------+-------------+-------------+
```

Across all the records that have an AdId of `179911`, I need the minimum `StartDate` (2017-01-04)and the maximum `EndDate` (2017-01-31) for a specific date of the month.

I would like to place the data I need for a specific date into a temp table.  I tried this:

```
declare @dt datetime
set @dt = '2017-01-19'

SELECT  
    MIN(dbo.aoadrundates.StartDate) AS MinStartDate,
    MAX(dbo.aoadrundates.EndDate) AS MaxEndDate,
    dbo.aoadrundates.AdId AS T_AdId
FROM
    dbo.aoadrundates 
WHERE
    StartDate >= @dt AND EndDate <= @dt
GROUP BY
    dbo.AoAdRunDates.AdId,
    dbo.aoadrundates.StartDate,
    dbo.aoadrundates.EndDate
```

but I only get the single record with the date I'm selecting, e.g.,

```
MinStartDate    MaxEndDate  T_AdId
2017-01-19      2017-01-19  179911
```

I tried a few examples I found that use cast, min, max as well as a subquery with an inner join, but these have not worked (I think) because I need both min from 1 row and max from another.

Please, if you don't really want to help me, that's fine.  If you can help, I would be most grateful. Thank you

Comment: Wow  I didn't expect that.  I of course have a lot more to do, so I was attempting a temp table.  I tried a few things like this:

Comment: @Barb I think what Ken was *trying* to say was: Welcome to Stack Overflow! As it currently stands your question is lacking the detail we need to help you solve your problem. You should check out [MCVE] and [ask] - they provide some good tips that will help you get a better response from the community here. Probably the most important thing is to include the code you're using in the question - it's probably the most important thing that new askers miss out. Asking for help is a learned skill :)

Comment: Thank you Jeff!  Very much appreciated.  Being new to Stack Overflow, I'm having a bit of difficulty posting my code.  I"ll keep trying.  Hopefully I'll encounter more folks like you and less like Ken.

Comment: Post your code by making an [edit] to your question. There's always a link to [edit] in the lower-left of your post, whether that post is a question or an answer. (In a question, it's just below the tags.) And MIN() and MAX() work whether the values are in the same row or not. It's difficult to say why your efforts didn't succeed, because *you didn't post any of those efforts*.

Comment: Thanks Ken.  I've tried again. I was attempting to make it simple, but after reading my own comments, even I wonder what the hell I'm taking about.  I'll try some more stuff and see if I can make a better example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem is that you're grouping by the fields you want to aggregate by - `dbo.aoadrundates.StartDate` and `dbo.aoadrundates.EndDate`. Assuming you're wanting to group by `AdId` you can use:

```
declare @dt datetime
set @dt = '2017-01-19'

SELECT  min(dbo.aoadrundates.StartDate) as MinStartDate,
        max(dbo.aoadrundates.EndDate)   as MaxEndDate,
        dbo.aoadrundates.AdId
from 
    dbo.aoadrundates 
    where StartDate >= @dt and EndDate <= @dt
group by
dbo.AoAdRunDates.AdId
```

From the comment "Across all the records" though you might want it repeated for every record with that `AdId`, in which case you're going to have to use a CTE or similar ([in 2012+ there are better ways](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213234(v=sql.110).aspx)...):

```
declare @dt datetime
set @dt = '2017-01-19'

;with cte_MinAndMax as (
    SELECT  min(dbo.aoadrundates.StartDate) as MinStartDate,
            max(dbo.aoadrundates.EndDate)   as MaxEndDate,
           dbo.aoadrundates.AdId
    from 
        dbo.aoadrundates 
        where StartDate >= @dt and EndDate <= @dt
    group by
    dbo.AoAdRunDates.AdId
)
select
    dbo.aoadrundates.AdId as T_AdId,
    cte_MinAndMax.MinStartDate,
    cte_MinAndMax.MaxEndDate,
    dbo.aoadrundates.whatever_else_you_want_to_select
from dbo.aoadrundates
left join cte_MinAndMax on dbo.aoadrundates.AdId = cte_MinAndMax.AdId
```

Comment: Oh!  The cte solution is getting me very close.  Thanks Jeff!

Comment: If the comment is useful, you can upvote, or if it solves your problem you can hit the check mark to mark this as the accepted answer. It's recommended that you don't do so for at least a few hours (I usually wait a day or two) because a better answer may show up (it's not likely to if you mark as accepted). Glad I could help :)